# How to print terminal formatted output to a variable

Tags: python

Is there a method to print terminal formatted output to a variable?

```
print 'a\bb'
--> 'b'
```

I want that string 'b' to a variable - so how to do it?

I am working with a text string from telnet. Thus I want to work with the string that would be printed to screen.

So what I am looking for is something like this:

```
simplify_string('a\bb') ==> 'b'
```

Another example with a carriage return:

```
simplify_string('aaaaaaa\rbb') ==> 'bbaaaaa'
```

Comment: To everyone posting methods to just capture stdout: you're missing the point. The issue is simplifying a string to account for *terminal control characters*, not just capturing `sys.stdout`.

Comment: @nneonneo: what's an example where capturing standard output wouldn't control for such characters?

Comment: @DavidRobinson: every case. He wants to have `\b` actually **delete the previous character**, effectively emulating the behaviour of `\b` as it would affect an actual terminal. Capturing `sys.stdout` does not emulate a terminal, it just captures any and all control sequences directly.

Comment: nneonneo is correct. I want those control characters out so that I can manipulate the string and search for things from there etc.

Comment: Two answers down, how many to go? This is what I call a good question ;)

Comment: @BartoszKP: four if you count the ones gone earlier...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This turns out to be quite tricky because there are a *lot* of terminal formatting commands (including e.g. cursor up/down/left/right commands, terminal colour codes, vertical and horizontal tabs, etc.).

So, if you want to emulate a terminal properly, get a terminal emulator! [`pyte`](https://github.com/selectel/pyte) (`pip install pyte`) implements a VT102-compatible in-memory virtual terminal. So, you can feed it some text, and then get the formatted text from it:

```
import pyte

screen = pyte.Screen(80, 24)
stream = pyte.ByteStream(screen)
stream.feed(b'xyzzz\by\rfoo')
# print the first line of text ('foozy')
print(screen.display[0].rstrip())
```

To handle multiple lines, just join all of the lines in the text (e.g. `'\n'.join(row.rstrip() for row in screen.display).rstrip()`).

Note that this doesn't handle trailing spaces, but those would be indistinguishable on a real terminal anyway.

Comment: Was just googling terminal emulators for python :) Nice job!

Comment: `'Screen' object does not support indexing` error on Python3.6

Comment: Is there a way to get character color&style when using color codes?

Comment: @SureshKota fixed. @БогданОпир: yes, please see the pyte documentation for [`Char`](https://pyte.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pyte.screens.Char). You can use `screen.buffer` to access the sparse array of `Char`s in the terminal buffer; each Char will include a color and style.